# Auto Archive Schedule; Time-based Trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, archive, schedule

I have been asked to create a live Google Sheets Spreadsheet to track the work schedule at our yard. I have no experience with a script but found out I could program my sheet instead of hiding formulas and it would yield a cleaner result. I have been able to make the sheet organize itself and I was able to make it Archive manually (onEdit). What I'm looking for is to have it automatically run the code at 1 am so when we arrive at work it archives based on a cell value in a certain column.

This is an example of my onEdit script that works, but when someone is trying to check off the "YES" column there is some lag and can cause the wrong cell to be checked, which I then manually correct.

```js
function onEdit() {
  var sheetNameToWatch = "Schedule";

  var columnNumberToWatch = 28;
  var valueToWatch = "Yes";
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Archive";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {

    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
  }
}
```

So this code runs at 100% failure but saves and executes, and I honestly don't know why. Could be I misunderstand the values I need to insert after the "function" area. I did have this setup with an "Auto Archive" trigger that created a menu button with a "Run" option on the sheet, but when you click that it only does the last row with "Yes" in column 28 (every press of the button will move 1 row until all rows are moved) and the button won't work for the other users of the sheet.

```js
function createTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("Move Archive") //Move Archive is the name of the script
    .timeBased()
    .everyMinutes(1) // only set to 1 minute for testing, I can change this out for a daily timer
    .create();
}


function myFunction() {
  var sheetNameToWatch = "Schedule"; // "schedule" is the sheet we enter info on

  var columnNumberToWatch = 28; //Column is "AB"
  var valueToWatch = "Yes";
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Archive"; //"Archive is the sheet the info is sent to"

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {

    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange); // I get its programmed for last row with "Yes" here, unsure on how to change this.
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());

    function myfunction() {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger("Move Archive"); // could have wrong value here

    }
  }
}
```

All I want is the sheet to "Archive" based on a "Yes" value in Column 28 (AB). I want every row with that column value to Archive at 1 am automatically. Any help is appreciated. If someone even wants to recommend a book or digital instruction for beginners that would be great.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up, I’m glad I’m allowed to post here. And for figuring out how to install the triggers I can do that, I believe my problem is knowing how to fill in the values within the triggers to achieve the result I’m looking for. I read over what you linked and it didn’t explain the values I have to add to the brackets in a trigger to have it interact with my script. My other issue will be that once the trigger works it might only pull the last row that meets the criteria, where I want it to pull all rows meeting the criteria. I believe I’ll need a loop or a different script.

Comment: The docs says that `newTrigger` takes name of function as argument, so in your case it will be `.newTrigger('myFunction')` if you have `function myFunction(){`

Comment: Okay, so that makes sense. I did try it that way as well and nothing happened on the sheet. I did see the trigger created and then deleted on the project page though.

Comment: If there's any sensitive information in your sheet or code make sure to remove it, but could you please provide a link to a copy of your sheet? It can be difficult to visualise spreadsheets without having a structure to look at

Comment: Added a link in the question.

Comment: Welcome. I've looked at your spreadsheet and I'd like to clarify something. The functions in your question are not the same as the ones in your spreadsheet. In the "Move Archive" project is appears as though you installed your onEdit function as a time-driven trigger. Is that right?

Comment: Apologies - a second clarification; again please correct me if I'm wrong. Your spreadsheet appears to have four project files - no problem there. However "Sort Schedule" has an onEdit(e) that runs a subroutine "multiSortColumns"; "Sort Railcars" also has an onEdit(e) that runs a subroutine "multiSortColumns"; and based on your question, "Move Archive" has a onEdit that is possibly configured as time-driven, every 5 minutes. Have I described this accurately?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it would work for the sort issue and the lag. So I copied it into a test sheet I created as when trying other codes I had looked up it deleted some lines. THis error comes up when trying to run the code
    //TypeError: Cannot read property "getRange" from undefined. (line 3, file "Code")
Also, I belive the code you wrote works entirely onEdit, which for the copy/paste/delete ("Archive") part will not work. For the "Archive" part I would need it to only run once at night, so that anything from the current day or that is incomplete (yes is not checked). 1/2

Comment: 2/2 And the archive sheet only needs to run when the sheet is open, or once a day like the "Archive" function, as no one will be editing the archive sheet unless a mistake is found and corrected. A link to the Test sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A03NmyxL7nqkx2P1XbbUE3TqHi1076WAPKH0i8ajb6g/edit#gid=512725089

Answer (score 0):

You have four project files each containing scripts of the same name, performing the same or similar tasks. You are experiencing lagging because you have multiple simple and installable scripts of the same name. Essentially, they are all trying to execute at the same time.

The following answer should be considered as one possible solution to your situation.

The elements of this script are:

- There is a single project file. Unnecessary project files have been deleted.
- There is a single function.
- The function is a single "simple" trigger (onEdit(e)) which takes advantage of the various event objects returns by onEdit. There are no installable triggers, and any/all installable triggers have been deleted.
- The function updates the "Schedule" and "Archive" sheets as described in the question; and then sorts both the "Schedule" and "Archive" sheets.
- If there is a change on the "Railcars" sheet, the function sorts that sheet.

---

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var testrange = e.range;
  var testsheet = testrange.getSheet();
  var testsheetname = testsheet.getSheetName();
  var testrow = testrange.getRow();
  var testcolumn = testrange.getColumn();
  var testvalue = e.value;
  var testsheetLC = testsheet.getLastColumn();
  var testsheetRange = testsheet.getRange(testrow,1,1,testsheetLC);
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the test sheet range is "+testsheetRange.getA1Notation()); 
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: Range: "+testrange.getA1Notation());
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: The row is "+testrow+", and the column is "+testcolumn);
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: The spreadheetsheet is "+e.source.getName()+", the sheet name is  "+testsheet+", the range = "+testrange.getA1Notation()+", and the new value = "+testvalue);
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));

  // Copy/Paste to Schedule/Archive
  var sheetNameSchedule = "Schedule";
  var colNumberSchedule = 28;
  var valueSchedule = "Yes";
  var sheetNameArchive = "Archive";

  // Sort Schedule
  var sortSchedule = [{column: 1, ascending: true},{column: 2, ascending: true},{column: 7, ascending: false}];// date // Appt (time) // Type (Out/In/RR)
  // Sort Railcars
  var sheetNameRailcars = "Railcars";
  var sortRailcars = [{column: 1, ascending: true}];

  if (testsheetname === sheetNameSchedule && testcolumn === colNumberSchedule && testvalue === valueSchedule){
    // this is a match
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: this was a match");

    // copy/paste to archive
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameArchive);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: the target range is "+targetRange.getA1Notation());
    testsheetRange.moveTo(targetRange);
    testsheet.deleteRow(testrow);

    // sort the Schedule Sheet
    var Avals = testsheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
    var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: The last row of content (in column A) = "+Alast+", and the last column = "+testsheetLC);
    var sortrange = testsheet.getRange(2,1,Alast-1,testsheetLC);
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: the sort range = "+sortrange.getA1Notation());
    sortrange.sort(sortSchedule);

    // sort the Archive Sheet
    var ATvals = targetSheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
    var ATlast = ATvals.filter(String).length;
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: The last row of content (in column A) = "+ATlast+", and the last column = "+testsheetLC);
    var sortrange = targetSheet.getRange(2,1,ATlast-1,testsheetLC);
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: the sort range = "+sortrange.getA1Notation());
    sortrange.sort(sortSchedule);
  }
  else if (testsheetname === sheetNameRailcars){

    // sort the sheet
    var Avals = testsheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
    var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: The last row of content (in column A) = "+Alast+", and the last column = "+testsheetLC);
    var sortrange = testsheet.getRange(2,1,Alast-1,testsheetLC);
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: the sort range = "+sortrange.getA1Notation());
    sortrange.sort(sortRailcars);
  } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an installable trigger to run this function at 1am every morning:

```
function scheduleToArchive() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var schedule = sheet.getSheetByName("Schedule");
  var archive = sheet.getSheetByName("Archive");
  var scheduleData = schedule.getRange(2, 1, (sheet.getRange('A:A').getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow()), 28);

  for (row = 2; row <= scheduleData.getNumRows(); row++){
    var data = schedule.getRange(row, 1, 1, 28).getValues();

    if (data[0][27] == 'Yes'){
     archive.getRange((archive.getLastRow() + 1), 1, 1, 28).setValues(data);
    }    
    schedule.getRange(row, 1, 1, 28).clear();
  }  
}
```

In your spreadsheet, when `getDataRange()` is run on the sheet named 'Schedule', it returns row 631 as the last row with data even though there is only data in the first 20 rows, so to get around that I've used `SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN` instead and run that on column A.

Comment: Hello, so this works great, all I need it to do is delete the copied row from the "Schedule" sheet once it is moved to the "Archive" sheet. I'll try and make that work but if anyone can let me know the easiest way that would be appreciated.
Got it, added:
        schedule.deleteRow(row);

Comment: @WarrenRoss Don't use `deleteRow()` - you'll run into trouble later down the line because there won't be any rows left so data can't be inputted and `getRange()` will throw an error. Get the range and use `clear()` instead as that clears the data without completely deleting the row. I've updated my answer so that the script will automatically clear the rows as it runs.

Comment: So I tested the clear function but it doesnt resort the sheet after it clears. I think Ill just use delete and add rows as needed. I think I could add a trigger driven by the clear but its one click to add a 1000 rows every couple months. Thank you everyone for you help with this!

Comment: @WarrenRoss Ah yes sorry - I'd included it inside the conditional instead of outside it. I've fixed it so if you want to automate it without having to worry about adding rows in the future it should work now.

Comment: Hello, so this had been working great until this week, it seems like lines go missing (they don't move to the archive sheet but are deleted from the schedule sheet) after the 1am trigger goes off. With the way this is written, does the "Yes" column need to be checked off sequentially? eg: row 2 and 4 are checked off as "Yes" but row 3 is not. Will it move row 2 and 4 without issue?